# How to override url params with rewrite rules vars?

Tags: php, wp-query, rewrite-rules

**Setup a rule:**

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^myparamname/?$', 'index.php?myparamname=hello', 'top' );
} );
```

**Whitelist the query param:**

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'myparamname';
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

**Get query vars:**

`localhost/myparamname`

```
get_query_var('myparamname'); // hello
```

`localhost/myparamname?myparamname=hi` or
`localhost/myparamname/?myparamname=hi`

```
get_query_var('myparamname'); // hi
```

As you can see, **"hi"** message is displayed instead of **"hello"** in the second example. Here, the desired situation is generally **"hello"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **"hi"** message is displayed instead of **"hello"** in the second example

Yes, because that's how it works: `query_vars` is a hook for registering custom query vars that are *public*, so if the URL query string contains the custom query var, then WordPress will set the query var to the value parsed from the query string.

> the desired situation is generally **"hello"**

You can override the query var via the [`request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/request/). E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'request', function ( $query_vars ) {
    if ( isset( $query_vars['myparamname'] ) ) {
        $query_vars['myparamname'] = 'hello';
    }

    return $query_vars;
} );
```

Just be sure to use a unique query var or be cautious that you don't override query var that shouldn't be overridden.

Comment: it's bad not being able to overwrite it as a dynamic variable. But thanks again.